# Linux make command

Tags: makefile, operating-system, gnu-make

I am trying to make a simple version of the Linux make command. I am a beginner to OS. Where should I start from? Can you suggest any links that will explain to me how to do it? I am not even sure where to start.

Comment: You can inspect source code of the GNU make here: http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/make/

Comment: make is quite huge piece of software. I would start with [its manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/index.html#Top) to better understand the problem. Then, maybe, reduce the scope of the problem.